# Как получать данные из финтес-приложения?

Tags: java, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-le, google-fit

Пытался создать android приложение, которое получает данные с фитнес-браслета "F1 Plus", но все гайды для более ранних API, поэтому пытаюсь понять как получать данные с приложения Wearfit.
Проект пишу на Java, программирование изучаю не так давно, так что надеюсь на понимание.
P.S. Если знаете как получать данные напрямую из браслета, просьба помочь.

Comment: Вопрос очень неточный. Его можно разделить на несколько полезных. Для начала вам нужно разобраться как общаться с bluetooth устройствами. Затем найти библиотеку или хотя бы описание протокола обмена с данным устройством (не факт что вы сможете найти)

Comment: Как я понял мы должны знать UUID сервисов и характеристик (их можно узнать и через сторонние приложения), однако через моё приложение оно возвращает пустой массив. Далее необходимо получение данных через профиль GATT.

Comment: Предложенная на Habr библиотека tinyB отказалась работать, возможно я не выполнил все условия работы с ней

Comment: Допустим. Я имел ввиду что в текущей формулировке на этот ответ наверняка не ответят по существу. Возможно даже закроют. Уточните с какими проблемами вы столкнулись и оставьте в одном вопросе одну проблему. Так, получая ответы, вы имеете шанс решить вашу задачу